# Weak delegates and .xib files

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, xib

Why are weak delegates not neeeded when using .xib files?

I made a simple project that doesn't use storyboards.  It just uses .xib files associated with UIViewControllers.  It presents the user with a button that when pressed, pushes a new viewcontroller and allows them to go back.  If the navDelegate below is listed as weak, then navigation to the DetailViewController never happens since navDelegate will always be nil.

SceneDelegate.swift

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let winScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
            return
        }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
        AppCoordinator().start()
    }
}
```

AppCoordinator.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol Coordinator: AnyObject {
    func start()
}

class AppCoordinator: Coordinator {
    let router = UINavigationController()

    func start() {
        let vc = RootViewController()

        vc.navDelegate = self
        router.viewControllers = [vc]
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
        window?.rootViewController = router
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

extension AppCoordinator: NavDelegate {
    func buttonTapped() {
        let vc = DetailViewController()
        router.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

RootViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol NavDelegate: AnyObject {
    func buttonTapped()
}

class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    // Does this navDelegate need to be weak when using .xib files?
    var navDelegate: NavDelegate?

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func tapDetailButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Always prints 2 no matter how many times I navigate back and forth
        let refCount = CFGetRetainCount(navDelegate)
        print("Ref Count: \(refCount)")
        navDelegate?.buttonTapped()
    }
}
```

DetailViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

So with further insight from @matt, it seems that if you have the AppCoordinator as an instance variable of the SceneDelegate then having the navDelegate as weak works.  I suppose the mistake is calling the navDelegate a delegate.  It should just be called something like a navHelper so there's no confusion as to whether it should be weak or not.

Comment: Information given to you by `CFGetRetainCount` is not useful at all. Don't count references, check whether there is an ownership cycle. Who owns (has a strong reference to) an instance?

Comment: @Sulthan Is there a way to do that through xcode?  I looked at the memory graph debugging and saw no leak issues or ownership cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with xibs. Or delegates either, really.

If you know what `weak` means, you know that it means "If no one else is holding a strong reference to this thing, let it go out of existence."

So when you say `vc.navDelegate = self`, where `self` in AppCoordinator instance, then if no other reference to this AppCoordinator instance retains it, it vanishes in a puff of smoke immediately afterward.

Well, what's the life story of this instance?

```
 AppCoordinator().start()
```

What does that line do? It creates an AppCoordinator instance, calls `start` on it, and then drops the AppCoordinator on the floor, letting it go out of existence if no one else is holding on to it. And no one else *is* holding on to it, because the only reference that anyone else had to it was `weak`.

Comment: Ok.  So when AppCoordinator is an instance variable of the SceneDelegate the refcount goes up from 2 to 3, but it's always at 3 no matter how many times I navigate back and forth.  Also, when I declare AppCoordinator as an instance variable of the SceneDelegate and declare the navDelegate as weak in the RootViewController navigation works and the refcount is 2.  So I guess the question I'm asking is declaring a delegate weak only necessary when it's held by another class as an instance variable.

Comment: @BobDave All delegates are held by another class as an instance variable. That's the purpose of delegates.

Comment: @Sulthan. I'm talking about the class that implements the delegate.  When it's held by another class vs. when it's just used in a function.

Comment: Don't use refcounts. Just thing about ownership. If no one owns an object it goes out of existence. Well, if the only persistent reference to an object is `weak`, no one owns it, so...

Comment: Also in answer to your question: the problem here is that you used the wrong word. This object is not a delegate.  Delegation means: "For this piece of functionality, I am willing to yield to some other object that already exists for some other purpose but might like to do this job _also_." You are not doing delegation, you're doing dependency injection. You are giving an object a helper object _which it owns_.